# Districts of Israel - free source

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries

Do you know of any free GIS sources of the [Israeli administrative divisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Districts_of_Israel): districts (mechozot, מחוזות) and subdistricts (nafot, נפות) which rely on official government information?

I heard there is a some free US government source, but failed to Google it.

**Update (2014-02-11):**

The Israeli government has opened a [national GIS website](http://beta.govmap.gov.il/home). The UI will make your eyes bleed, the interface is only in Hebrew and there is no way to download the source files, only "save map as image".

On the other hand, it's the only official source. The map can be zoomed and downloaded chunk-by-chunk and georeferenced using QGis or alike. Depending on the required accuracy, this process can take anywhere between 30 minutes to a few hours and produce good-enough results.

[Permalink to the Administrative boundaries layer](http://beta.govmap.gov.il/?c=gtLcOLAQgLUePG9Nan0gjw==%7CeJMvFZaetoUdf0XOvFER0Q==&z=0&b=0&lay=REGION).

Comment: Did you check Open Street Map ?

Comment: They don't have this layer, and the data there is usually non-official.

Comment: You could try: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i dont think info like this in free GIS sources existe. you can try to use arcscan to scan a map and make it a shp file. 
http://gis.cbs.gov.il/shnaton57/all_israel-2006.pdf
we did something like this to a map of tel aviv in a gis-database course in baraln

Comment: +1 Nice idea, if we can make it accurate enough.

Answer (score 2):

Is the data from [Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org) of any use to you? You can find the dataset for Israel here: [Global Administrative Areas - Israel](http://gadm.org/data/shp/ISR_adm.zip)

Comment: +1 Thanks, but the geometries seems a bit inaccurate AFAIK, and I'm not sure how official the source - I'll mail the site.

Comment: Another issue - the data is not free for commercial use.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=31.5011501312256&lon=34.7492408752441&zoom=12).
And [Gis Center at Hebrew University](http://hugis.huji.ac.il) too. You may need to contact them by email.

[image: Opensteetmap]

Comment: +1 I've contacted HUGIS, but they don't have these layers. OSM has some sever licensing and integrity problems for commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried searching in [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/)? The data there is in public domain, but I don't know whether they have lower-level admin. boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

What about this from the DIVA-GIS website and their spatial data are free. 
[DIVA GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata)